# Fetch text from word document page wise

Tags: php, ms-word

I am working on lawyer site. I want to manage the document uploaded in the system. I want to fetch the content of document page wise in php array.

```
 $array = [
       [0] => 'Page 1 Content',
       [1] => 'Page 2 Content',
       [2] => 'Page 3 Content',
    ];
```

I've tried following but not getting output as an array

```
<?php
    include_once("DocxConversion.php");

    $docObj = new DocxConversion("sample.docx");
    $docText = $docObj->convertToText(0);

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($docText);
?>
```

It is showing all text of document as a text not as an array. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because what constitutes a "page" depends on factors like page size and font and text size. And they're variables (some) outside of the body of the document.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because Word does not save paging information for content that doesn't contain "hard page breaks". (It's barely possible to get content by page when a document is open in the Word application - the object model doesn't even have a Page object.)

If you need to get the information by page the document should be saved to something like PDF format, where the paging is static and the information saved in the file.

Word is a word processor. Unlike page layout software, the content is not assigned to a "page object". It's a "flow" of text characters that the Word application lays out dynamically when the document is opened and edited in Word. Many factors contribute to the dynamic automatic layout: printer, printer driver, font characteristics, etc. This means the optimal layout may be different when the document is opened on other machines. So paging (and line break) information is not saved in the document.

Comment: thanks Cindy, @user3327608 Find yourself a good library that does that for example https://pdfparser.org/ or https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check it